# Cordova - Android updates (freeze versions)

Tags: android, cordova

If I need to do some updates in my cordova app (HTML, JS, CSS) after a few months or weeks, running `cordova build android --release --buildConfig` gives me an error.

Usually opening android studio and installing all the updates fixes the errors.

Facts:

- I didn't remove the platform
- Last time it worked just fine
- no update was made to my laptop, android studio or any software.

Looks like, in time, the cordova code remains outdated and the build knows that and forces me to update in order to build.

How can I make the cordova project maintain it's own core resources/plugins and be able to build my JS/HTML/CSS without worrying if the latest android SDK does not comply with a plugin or cordova version?

Comment: Have you fixed the version of android you compile with in the `config.xml` ? You can do it by adding this property : `<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="23">`

Comment: "`cordova build android --release --buildConfig` gives me an error" - probably it makes sense to include the error into the question?

Comment: @daserge -- the error it's different every time. The question in not about the error, is about why it requires updates. For every error I get, I search on google and the SDK update resolves it usually.

Comment: @AdrianFlorescu, does the issue happen after you update Cordova? `Looks like, in time, the cordova code remains outdated and the build knows that and forces me to update in order to build.` - Cordova does not check how old is your code, so there should be some changes either in platform or cordova tools.

Comment: @daserge no, no cordova update. I simply don't understand how after a week from the last build (published in playstore) the same command fails to run due to different issues mainly caused by SDK or some updates required.

Comment: That seems strange for me too. I believe it would help to investigate if you could add the error details.

Comment: Please post your build output.

Comment: @Frix33 - as I mentioned above, the question is not about a particular error, it's about how can I freeze my build environment until I am prepared to update the SDKs, cordova, and the plugins manually.

Comment: @Frix33 current error `Error:(186, 0) NDK integration is deprecated in the current plugin.
<a href="http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental">Consider trying the new experimental plugin</a><br><a href="useDeprecatedNdk">Set "android.useDeprecatedNdk=true" in gradle.properties to continue using the current NDK integration</a>`

Comment: Try this: `cordova build android --release --gradleArg=android.useDeprecatedNdk=true`

Answer (score 6):

You don't really say if you are using any tool sets outside of vanilla Cordova, so take a look at [TACO](http://taco.tools/index.html). It wouldn't necessarily be my first pick for Cordova tool kits, but if you want a Cordova build tool that manages the SDK setup for you, TACO does that (as opposed to something like Ionic which requires you to manage the SDK for Android/iOS separately).

> To install the 3rd party dependencies for Android, run
>
> `taco install-reqs android`
>
> The above command first checks for the following dependencies and installs them if found missing:
>
> - Java JDK
> - Android SDK (includes ADB and gradle as part of the install,
>     as well as all necessary Android packages)

**Source:** http://taco.tools/docs/configure-platform.html

[PhoneGap Build](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/overview/) and [IntelXDK](https://software.intel.com/intel-xdk) build remotely for free, and they manage the SDK libraries for you and you can build iOS projects without owning a Mac (you send up your HTML/JS/CSS and a build file, get back an APK/IPA). Telerik has some build service as well, but I think you have to subscribe to it. But with all three of those, I think you have to go whole hog and completely migrate your project to their tool kits. TACO should be less invasive to your current project.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't use any tool sets, just command line. I have Android Studio installed, but just because it was apparently required in order to build the android project.

Comment: The question was if I can freeze the version, not to be managed by other tools. I guess these tools will still do updates, and if a plugin will be left behind by it's maintainers, I will still be unable to build. Anyways, I'll get back to you as soon as I get a chance to play with the tools mentioned above.